The set of Points where the Birkhoff Sum goes to infinity has measure zero
I came up with the following question when studying Birkhoff ergodic theorem.
Let $(X,\mu,T)$ be an ergodic measure preserving system and $f\in L^1_{\mu}(X)$ be an integrable function. The Birkhoff ergodic theorem states that $A_n(x):= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(T^i x)$ converges to $\int_{X}fd\mu$ almost surely and in $L^1$ as $n\to \infty$.
I am curious about the following problem. If we put the additional assumption that $\int_{X}fd\mu = 0$ and define $E = \{x\in X | \lim_{n\to \infty} f(x) + f(Tx)+ \cdots + f(T^{n-1}x) = \infty
\}$, is it ture that $\mu(E) = 0$ always holds? (i.e. , E is the set on which the sum along orbit(without averaging!) goes to infinity)
Any help or comment would be highly appreciated.

Here are some attempts I have made. It's easy to see that $E$ is $T$-invariant. Therefore if $E$ is not of zero measure, then it must have measure $1$. Then since $T$ is measure-preserving, we get
$$0 = \int_{X} A_n (x)d\mu(x) = \int_{E} A_n (x)d\mu(x)$$
and $A_n (x)$ goes to infinity pointwise on $E$. This looks quite hopeful to produce a contradiction, given that $\frac{1}{n} A_n (x)$ converges to $0$ both pointwisely and in $L^1$.  But I can't work it out.

If $\int_X fd\mu = 0$, then almost sure convergence implies that for almost every $x\in X$, $\lim_{n\to \infty} A_n(x) = 0$.  Therefore, the set $E$ has measure zero.  Your definition of $A_n(x)$ already has a factor of $\frac{1}{n}$ in front.
EDIT for modified question:  That's a good question.  In general, we can't expect that limit to be finite.  Both of these are possible depending on $T$ and $f$:
$$ (1)\ \limsup_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(T^ix) = \infty\ \mbox{for almost every}\ x .$$
$$ (2)\ \ 0 < \limsup_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(T^ix) < \infty\ \mbox{for almost every}\ x.$$
If the function $f$ is a coboundary for $T$ with a transfer function $g$, that implies $f,g,T$ satisfy the equation: $f(x)=g(x)-g(Tx)$ for almost every $x$.  In this case, when you plug this into the sum, it becomes telescoping and you will get:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(T^ix) = g(x) - g(T^{n}x)\ \ \mbox{a.e.}.$$
If $g$ is bounded, then $\limsup < \infty$ a.e.  It's unusual to be able to express $f,g,T$ in this way.  This paper shows how unusual this is without further assumptions: https://tinyurl.com/4zxfmvtn.  Given any $T$, it's not difficult to construct a mean-zero bounded function $f$ such that the $\limsup = \infty$.  Here is a previous post of a result of Kakutani-Petersen: https://mathoverflow.net/a/206744/503770.  (Please genuflect as you pass over Terry Tao's 2015 comment.)
Also, for a mean-zero non-trivial function $f$, it may not be possible to actually have the limit go to infinity, since $f<0$ on a set of positive measure.  Very recent results show that you should expect fluctuation around the mean infinitely often, or $f$ will be a coboundary.  See theorem 3.5 of this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2404.11507.  So the answer is No.  In general, there is no convergence rate for the Birkhoff ergodic theorem.

You are right. I made a typo. I have edited the original question. What I am intersted in is the set where the sum along orbit( without averaging) goes to infinity.

@JNF, see answer to your modified question.  I noticed that you wrote limit.  I don't think the actual limit will exist for a non-trivial function $f$.  The $\limsup$ can be $\infty$.

The fluctuation result you mentioned really surprises me. Thanks for the reply and for introducing such wonderful  theorems to me!

You're welcome!  I agree the result on fluctuations is surprising.
